# How do I apply a dictionary of functions to a dictionary in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I've got a state variable `s`, and I want to apply a dictionary of functions to it:

```
s: `peg`pos`ent`exi!(0n 0n 1 2)
f: `peg`pos`ent`exi!({null x};{null x}; {null x}; {null x})
```

I attempted

```
f s
f @ s
```

But neither of these worked. What am I doing wrong? The expected result would be

```
`peg`pos`ent`exi!(0b 0b 1b 1b)
```

(Just as background, I'm trying to build a state machine and thought the 'KDB' way of doing it might be a truth table, although if there's a better way please let me know!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add  `'`, the each iterator.

```
q)f @' s
peg| 1
pos| 1
ent| 0
exi| 0
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. I never tire of how KDB seems to operate like a piece of beautiful mathematics! Thank you for help, again! :)